# Databricks and Delta cache setting

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to follow the instructions on the MSFT website to use delta cache and hoping someone would help me understand it a little better:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/optimizations/delta-cache

So In the guide it mentions that I should use Standard_E or L series of VMs. Our workload is now set to use the F series machines and when I tried to use only E or L it seemed that the job ran longer and would be using more DBUs.

I did however notice that the Dv3 series allow you to use delta caching (ex: Standard_D16s_v3 VMs). I tried to run some of our workloads using those types of machines and notices that under the storage tab it now shows a similar screen as in the MSFT docs:

[image]

Problem is that I am not sure if that is the right way to go about this. The reason I wanted to try to use Dv3 VMs was because it was relatively comparable to the F series, but also seem to allow the delta caching.

I am also wondering if the MSFT recommendation of using the following settings is correct or if they can be different:

```
spark.databricks.io.cache.maxDiskUsage 50g
spark.databricks.io.cache.maxMetaDataCache 1g
spark.databricks.io.cache.compression.enabled false
```

Has any one else played with this and can recommend what they did it would be much appreciated.

As background we have the databricks clusters spin up using our Databricks Linked Service (from ADF) and in that linked service we put the following settings:

[image]

This is what sends the config settings to the automated clusters that are spun up when we execute Databricks notebooks though ADF.

Thank you